# Math.round() not working properly

Tags: java, android, rounding, rounding-error

This is my program. very simply put, it is supposed to round an entered number to a given amount of decimals. I.e. 4.245 rounded to 2 decimals would give 4.25. However, I always only get it rounded to an integer back... Why? What is puzzling me is that I use the same code in android and it works flawlessly

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Rounder {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double input1, roundednumber;
    int input2;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("number to round ");
    input1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("decimals");
    input2 = keyboard.nextInt();

    roundednumber = rounder(input1, input2);
    System.out.println(roundednumber);
}


public static double rounder(double number, int decimals){
    int multiplier = (int) Math.pow(10, decimals);
    double roundednumber;
    roundednumber = Math.round(number*multiplier)/multiplier;
    return roundednumber;       
}
}
```

And here is the snippet from my android class

```
double result1 = fv1/(Math.pow(1+(r1/n1),n1*t1));
result1 = (double) (Math.round(result1 * 100)) / 100;
```

Comment: You can better try [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for rounding purpose..

Comment: You are doing an integer divide: Math.round() returns an int and you divide by an int. Write Math.round(...)/(double) multiplied; instead.

Comment: Trying to do "decimal" rounding like this with `double`s is almost guaranteed to get you bad results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dividing by an integer produces an integer, so you can use:

```
Math.round(number * multiplier) / (double)multiplier;
```

Comment: Thanks... completely forgot that i divide by an int ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
roundednumber = Math.round(number*multiplier)/((double)(multiplier));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because Math.round() returns an int and you are dividing by an int. Thus resulting in int.